# Mysql union Priority

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables and my query is :

```
SELECT BRAND, AMOUNT FROM
(
SELECT BRAND, AMOUNT FROM SALES1 
UNION
SELECT BRAND, AMOUNT FROM SALES2
UNION
SELECT BRAND, AMOUNT FROM SALES3
)
```

`SALES 1` TABLE HAS BRAND: *A* AND AMOUNT: *50*

`SALES 3` TABLE HAS BRAND: *A* AND AMOUNT: *100*

I want to get the amount 50 and disregard 100. I want to ask if is there any priority when using union?

Comment: Do you have a `brands` table that has all brands? And would you prefer rows with zeroes for brands that sold nothing or no row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the first occurrence, you should use `union all` rather than `union`.  This is important for performance reasons, because `union` does unnecessary duplicate elimination.

Then use the `not exists` clauses for each subquery:

```
(SELECT BRAND, AMOUNT
 FROM SALES1 
) UNION ALL
(SELECT BRAND, AMOUNT
 FROM SALES2 s2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SALES1 s1 WHERE s1.BRAND = s2.BRAND)
) UNION ALL
(SELECT BRAND, AMOUNT
 FROM SALES3 s3
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SALES1 s1 WHERE s1.BRAND = s3.BRAND) AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SALES2 s2 WHERE s2.BRAND = s3.BRAND)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  BRAND, AMOUNT
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  BRAND, AMOUNT, 1 AS priority
            FROM  SALES1
            UNION  ALL 
        SELECT  BRAND, AMOUNT, 2 AS priority
            FROM  SALES2
            UNION  ALL 
        SELECT  BRAND, AMOUNT, 3 AS priority
            FROM  SALES3 
      )
    ORDER BY  priority
    LIMIT  1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a `"where not exists"`(or `"not in"` or a `"left join"`) within your `union`s:

```
(SELECT BRAND, AMOUNT FROM SALES1 )
UNION 
(SELECT BRAND, AMOUNT FROM SALES2) 
UNION 
(SELECT BRAND, AMOUNT FROM SALES3 where brand not in (SELECT BRAND FROM SALES1))
```